# Is it possible to protect encryption key from being read by malicious app in iOS/Android?

Tags: android, ios, security

I'm currently trying to build an authentication application in Android which stores users' username and password in the memory. Since sensitive information is stored, it would have to be encrypted.

And also the point is that the user does not need to enter a password, I would like to make it such that there is no master password for the app, assuming that the handset is secure.

As such, the encryption key would have to be stored somewhere. My question is, is there any mechanism in iOS/Android that protects my encryption key from being read by a malicious application with root access?

EDIT: I think it should be possible since web browsers store passwords, and I haven't heard a way to extract them.

Comment: Actually it is possible to extract passwords from webbrowsers, just google around a bit.

Comment: The human element is what it comes down to, you'll have to use a typed in password because once a phone is rooted, or webserver, there is full access to everything on that device. A determined person will be able to decompile your app, find the key, see through your obfuscations and unlock the password store.

Comment: @Dan S: Using a typed password wont help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO**, the user of your application has more control over the platform than you do.  Or in this case if the phone was stolen,  the new user has full control over the device.  There is no place to hide a secret on any device.  The same is true for desktop applications, mobile applications and web browsers.

Comment: @Bo Tian Okay well look at consoles.  Every console ever created has had pirated games for it.   The xobx360 was broken before it came out due to a problem with the optical drive's firmware.